# Docker Build on node:alpine-lts suddenly not working anymore

Tags: node.js, docker

Following my Dockerfile

```bash
FROM node:lts-alpine as node
ARG STAGE='dev'
ARG STAGEPATH='/dev'
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --configuration $STAGE --base-href=${STAGEPATH}/konnektor/
```

I execute manually
`docker build --progress=plain --no-cache -t konnektor .`

And get the following Error

```
#14 [node 6/6] RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --configuration dev --base-href=/dev/konnektor/
#14 sha256:0d47aa4d98557f141c02bf395f4e2f6dd49e9cebe6dddad4ea4e5126da5016e7           
#14 10.72 /bin/sh: Unknown: not found
#14 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c $(npm bin)/ng build --configuration $STAGE --base-href=${STAGEPATH}/konnektor/]: exit code: 127
------> [node 6/6] RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --configuration dev --base-href=/dev/konnektor/:
```

The build was working yesterday morning. I figured out, that the parentimage "node:lts-alpine" got an update a few hours ago. So i strongly think this is the problem. My problem now is, how can i get my build up and running again? The last Image was overwritten by this build and docker.io does not give older digest-hashes to pull older images.

I tried to get older Image-Versions without success on docker.io.

I saw, that other alpine-containers were updated on the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others, maybe facing the same problem, here my fix:

I was able to fix my setup by hardwiring the Digest of the Dockerimage to the version before.

The problem was, finding the digest hash-values of the images. They are not to find in docker.io (only the most recent hash).

But fortunately, there is an repo keeping track of the Versions:
https://github.com/docker-library/repo-info/blob/master/repos/node/remote/lts-alpine.md

Following the git-history of lts-alpine.md gave me the older image-hash. Accordingly i changed

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as node
```

to

```
FROM node@sha256:fda98168118e5a8f4269efca4101ee51dd5c75c0fe56d8eb6fad80455c2f5827 as node
```